# How to replace all occurrences by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `package.json` and some of the dependencies versions are:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@octopol/common": "workspace:packages/common",
  }
...
```

I want to replace all these (`workspace:packages/<something>`) versions with, for example, `1.0.0`.

I tried this:

```
`"@octopol/common": "workspace:packages/common","@octopol/aa": "workspace:packages/aa",`
.replace(/(workspace:packages\/(.*))/g, "1.0.0")
```

I was expecting to get:

`"@octopol/common": "1.0.0","@octopol/aa": "1.0.0",`

But the result was:

`'"@octopol/common": "1.0.0'`

What am I missing here?

Comment: `"@octopol/common": "workspace:packages/common","@octopol/aa": "workspace:packages/aa",`
.replace(/(?!\")(workspace:packages\/(.*?)(?=\"))/g, "1.0.0"); https://regex101.com/r/DxCUlt/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` matches till the end of the line, and since your input is a single line, `/(workspace:packages\/(.*))/g` matches `workspace:packages/` and then  any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, till the end of the line. You need to temper the dot in some way.

A possible solution can look like

```js
console.log(
    `"@octopol/common": "workspace:packages/common","@octopol/aa": "workspace:packages/aa",`
.replace(/workspace:packages\/[^"]*/g, "1.0.0")
);
```

where `workspace:packages\/[^"]*` matches

- `workspace:packages\/` - `workspace:packages/` string
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`.

If the part to be replaced cannot contain whitespace, you can further precise the pattern as `/workspace:packages\/[^"\s]*/g`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/reaMPW/1).